# Create a Weighted NetworkX DiGraph from python dict of dicts descripton

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

I have a Python dictionary like this one: `{0: {1: 10, 2: 1}, 1: {2: 1}, 2:{3: 1}, 3: {1: 1}}`

Where each key of the top dictionary is an origin node, each key of the value dictionary is an accesible node from it and it value is the cost to go there. For example, you can go from `0` to `1` with cost `10`.

Now I want to construct a *NetworkX* `DiGraph` from it. Reading the documentation of *NetworkX* I understood that I can use `nx.DiGraph(incoming_graph_data=my_dict_of_dicts)` to make the `DiGraph`, but I loss the costs between nodes when I create it.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your inner dictionaries, for instance convert `{1: 10, 2: 1}` to `{1: {'weight':  10}, 2: {'weight': 1}}`. See [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_dict_of_dicts.html#networkx.convert.from_dict_of_dicts), here is some code:

```
import networkx as nx

my_dict_of_dicts = {0: {1: 10, 2: 1}, 1: {2: 1}, 2: {3: 1}, 3: {1: 1}}

for k, d in my_dict_of_dicts.items():
    for ik in d:
        d[ik] = {'weight': d[ik]}

g = nx.DiGraph(my_dict_of_dicts)

for s, t, w in g.edges(data=True):
    print(s, t, w)
```

**Output**

```
0 1 {'weight': 10}
0 2 {'weight': 1}
1 2 {'weight': 1}
2 3 {'weight': 1}
3 1 {'weight': 1}
```

Or as an alternative you could use a generator expression:

```
import networkx as nx

my_dict_of_dicts = {0: {1: 10, 2: 1}, 1: {2: 1}, 2: {3: 1}, 3: {1: 1}}
g = nx.DiGraph((k, v, {'weight': weight}) for k, vs in my_dict_of_dicts.items() for v, weight in vs.items())

for s, t, w in g.edges(data=True):
    print(s, t, w)
```

**Output**

```
0 1 {'weight': 10}
0 2 {'weight': 1}
1 2 {'weight': 1}
2 3 {'weight': 1}
3 1 {'weight': 1}
```

**UPDATE**

As @eduhs mentioned you need to add the unconnected vertices, for that you could add this line after creating the graph:

```
g.add_nodes_from(my_dict_of_dicts.keys())
```

Comment: Testing this code, I found that if you have some unconected vertex, they doesn't appear in the NetworkX Graph because the function to create it uses the edges. I solved it adding this line after creating the Graph `g.add_nodes_from(my_dict_of_dicts.keys())`